# Como implemento um LinhaGuia horizontal e vertical utilizando NVD3.js?

Tags: javascript, gráfico, d3.js

A biblioteca NVD3 não dá suporte para uma linha guia horizontal, e a vertical não pode ser controla e não retorna valores que intercepta no gráfico. Qual a melhor solução para utilizá-la no meu projeto? Fazer um fork no repositório e eu mesmo implementar?

Comment: Já experimentaste sugerir um pull request para essa biblioteca?

Comment: Vou tentar. Obrigado.